# Add wndproc hooks to a Win32 window

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop

I have a native VB6 window and I want to listen in .NET for when it changes position or size to reposition a WPF window. I tried this in a .NET class `HwndSource.fromHWnd(VB6FormHWnd)` but it just returns null instead of an HwndSource instance. I imagine this is because the window wasn't originally created to host WPF content? I don't really know for sure. I wanted to use it's `addHook` function.

I know there is a method of some kind of "subclassing" in VB6 to handle WndProc messages and I could call some kind of .NET service from VB6 within the WndProc handler to broadcast or forward messages. I tried that in the past with some success, but the subclassing gets tricky and causes crashing issues for me when debugging (via the VB6 editor).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.assignhandle?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFYI, the are no crashes with [The Modern Subclassing Thunk (MST)](https://github.com/wqweto/ModernSubclassingThunk) in VB6 IDE whatsoever.

You might crash because of some other problems but not because of wrong subclassing handling.

Comment: Excellent. This should work for me. Thank you for letting me know.